# Rectangle Coordinate Rotation

Tags: math, rotation

I want to rotate rectangles on a centre point rectangle.

For example I have grid of rectangles size 41 x 21

So my centre rectangle is 20 x 10

Now I wanna rotate 22 x 14 to 90 degree along centre rectangle.

What will be formula to rotate 22 x 14.

any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, project the cells onto a plane, then use a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), then project them cells back into the grid.  For this example, its overkill, but works nonetheless.

---

You need to set your origin to be (21,11) not (0,0) so first translate your points

```
[x'] := [x - 21]
[y']    [y - 11]
```

Then apply the rotation matrix transform (note that I'm assuming traditional direction of axes)

```
[x''] := [ cos(-Pi/2)   -sin(-Pi/2) ][x']      =  [ y']
[y'']    [ sin(-Pi/2)    cos(-Pi/2) ][y']         [-x']
```

Then un-translate the origin.  Because your plane wasn't square, the resultant rotated plane is a different shape (it measures 21x41 with origin 11,21). I've assumed this is what you wanted, and you didn't want points to be able to "fall off" the plane.

```
[x'''] := [x'' + 11]
[y''']    [y'' + 21]
```

Simplifying the algebra, this boils down to the map

```
[x]  ->  [  y ]
[y]      [42-x]
```

**Answer**

(22,14) rotates to (14,20)

---

Note: Counting from 1, I make the centre of 41x21 as 21x11, not 20x10?

Comment: Thanks James, look at grid it 7,7 grid with centre point 3,3

6,0 6,1 6,2 6,3 6,4 6,5 6,6
5,0 5,1 5,2 5,3 5,4 5,5 5,6
4,0 4,1 4,2 4,3 4,4 4,5 4,6
3,0 3,1 3,2 3,3 3,4 3,5 3,6
2,0 2,1 2,2 2,3 2,4 2,5 2,6
1,0 1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 1,5 1,6
0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 0,5 0,6

90 degree
Centre Point = 3,3

4,3 >> 3,4 >> 2,3 >>3,2
5,3 >> 3,5 >> 1,3 >> 3,1
6,3 >> 3,6 >> 0,3 >> 3,0


What will the formula if we want to rotate 90 degree each box

Comment: is that same formula can be applied on different angles like 7,20 or 190?